# Algebra and matrices.

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-equations

Q. Solve for $x$, $y$ and $z$ if

$$(x+y)(x+z)=15, $$
$$(y+z)(y+x)=18, $$
$$(z+x)(z+y)=30. $$

Solution:
I expanded each equation above as :

$$x^2+xz+yx+yz=15, \tag{1}$$
$$y^2+xz+yx+yz=18, \tag{2}$$
$$z^2+xz+yx+yz=30. \tag{3}$$

Then I subtracted $(1)-(3)$, $(2)-(1)$ and $(3)-(2)$; so I got the equations as below:
$$x^2-z^2=-15 \tag{4}$$
$$y^2-x^2=3 \tag{5}$$
$$z^2-y^2=12 \tag{6}$$

I then tried solving $(4)$,$(5)$,$(6)$ by using matrices, but I couldn't reach any solution.

Please advise. Thank You.

Comment: This is a nightmare to read. Try typesetting using MathJax to make it easier for us to read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take $x+y=a,y+z=b,x+z=c$. Then you get

$ac=15\quad[1]$

$ab=18\quad[2]$

$bc=30\quad[3]$

Multiply to get $(abc)^2=8100$, thus getting $abc=90$.

Divide by $[1],[2],[3]$ separately to get

$a=3$

$b=6$

$c=5$

Now, substitute to get

$x+y=3\quad[4]$

$y+z=6\quad[5]$

$x+z=5\quad[6]$

Add to get $x+y+z=7$

Subtract separately to get

$x=1,y=2,z=4$.

**EDIT**

As @hkBst pointed out, we could also get $abc=-90$, thus giving

$x=-1,y=-2,z=-4$.

Comment: Thank You very much @MalayTheDynamo

Comment: nice answer. @MalayTheDynamo

Comment: or abc = -90 with all three variables negative... no idea if it leads to an additional solution

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's request "Please advise." It's just another answer to the original question.

Comment: I tried solving again by matrices; and I got infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @MathTise Then, quite obviously, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Would love to get your thoughts on [m,n,p-games](https://www.reddit.com/r/abstractgames/comments/8khl96/formal_definition_of_mnpgames/) (see the [Mbrane app](http://mbranegame.com/))  *(The secret history of M holds that it originated with the Vedic mathematician [Manava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manava) per his work on the geometrical construction of fire altars, but other sources claim it originated from the Duke of Zhou to teach strategy on the eve of the [Battle of Muye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Muye), per the game's defection mechanic.